# Как сделать фоновое изображение таким?

Tags: html, css

Часто вижу на сайтах что фоновое изображение имеет какой-то эффект, на фоне которого отчётливо видно текст. Не понимаю, то ли это размытие, то ли затемнение. Подскажите, как сделать что-то похожее?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: задайте фону цвет `rgba(0,0,0, .5)` - 4 параметр прозрачность от 0 до 1.

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв. Не совсем понял. Можно пример пожалуйста?

Comment: создаётся некий overlay т.е фон который перекрывает светлое изображение ...и на этом тёмном overlay светлый текст и логотип видно хорошо ...есть более красивые решения но они пока не кроссбраузерны

Comment: Вот мне так и нужно. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 32px;
  background-image: url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/uw-s3-cdn/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2017/11/04133712/waterfall.jpg');
  z-index: 1;
}

.container::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  content: "";
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  Text
</div>
```

Comment: У Вас выводится фоновое изображение в Вашем коде? У меня нет.

Comment: Нажми "Выполнить код", все показывает.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что Вы ищете blur эффект, так называемый эффект размытия. Ниже представлен пример:

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.bg-image {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("https://www.w3schools.com/howto/photographer.jpg");
  
  /* Add the blur effect */
  filter: blur(8px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
  
  /* Full height */
  height: 100%; 
  
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

/* Position text in the middle of the page/image */
.bg-text {
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.4); /* Black w/opacity/see-through */
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 2;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-image"></div>

<div class="bg-text">
  <h2>Blurred Background</h2>
  <h1 style="font-size:50px">I am John Doe</h1>
  <p>And I'm a Photographer</p>
</div>
```

#### Ссылки по теме

- [How TO - Blurred Background Image](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_blurred_background.asp)
- [Поддержка браузерами эффектов CSS Filter](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters)